# Pesquisar frase no banco de dados

Tags: php

Olá

Eu estou recebendo um parâmetro via **GET** que é uma frase ( O Rato Roeu a Roupa do Rei de Roma ) e desejo por meio de um **SELECT** utilizando a clausula **WHERE** pesquisar esta frase no banco de dados, respeitando o espaçamento entre as palavras. Como eu posso fazer ?

Obrigado

Comment: Não seria apenas `where frase = '$_GET[frase]'`, ou semelhante? Ou melhor, edite a pergunta e descreva a estrutura do seu banco, principalmente a coluna onde irá realizar a busca.

Comment: O que você tentou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for MySQL, você pode usar o LOCATE ou o LIKE:

```
"Select * from tabela where LOCATE('". $_GET["frase"] ."', campo) > 0"

"Select * from tabela where campo LIKE '%". $_GET["frase"] ."%'"
```